# JAVA : How to invalidate all JWT token of particular user?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I have a project where currently there is a functionality where multiple user session is enabled. But now I want to make it something like when a new user logged in, then all other sessions of that user will be invalidated. User authentication is based on JWT Token. So how can I invalidate all the existing JWT Tokens of that user and keep only the new one?

Note: Currently I am not storing JWT Token in Database and I don't want that because it leaks the security.

Here is the class for JWTTokenUtils from where I generate the token and validate it.

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Constants.JWTToken.SIGNING_KEY.getBytes()))
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(String userId) {
        return doGenerateToken(userId);
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(String userId) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(userId);
        claims.put("scopes", Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setId(userId)
                .setIssuer(null)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Constants.JWTToken.SIGNING_KEY.getBytes()))
                .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT")
                .compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())
                && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn’t the fact that you *can’t* invalidate JWT’s something that’s by design? You say you don’t want to store them in a DB because that “*leaks security*”, can you elaborate on that? Plenty of applications use this approach without major security implications.

Comment: The project is secured and certified with PCI Security Standards Council, and to match and follow the standards, we can't store it.

Comment: Can you not have a session id in the JWT token, which you do store, and can remove from the DB when you want to invalidate the tokens?

Comment: Or just store a date for each user, and ignore any JWT tokens issued before that date, even if they haven't expired.

Comment: @tgdavies Best not to mix session IDs with JWT IMHO.  Also, use a cache, not the database, for storing such state (the DB will not scale very well).

Comment: @KishanSolanki, why don't you just change the JWT secret key instead. then all JWT token issued before will not be accepted !!

Comment: @KhajaMdSherEAlam can you elaborate with some code snippet?

Comment: @tgdavies workaround with the date and JWT created a nice solution. On new login, I stored token expire date and when from other device user makes a request, I validated his/her token's expire date with the stored date and given un-authorise if it doesn't match.

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this, you basically need to persist some sort of state, somewhere.  One general approach which you may consider would be to maintain a *blacklist* cache of users who should be blocked.  In your particular case, you could also store a date associated with each user.  For each incoming request, you would first quickly hit the blacklist cache and make sure that the incoming JWT's date were not too old.  Of course, you could assert the `exp` claim, because perhaps the incoming JWT be already expired in the first place.

The key point here is to use a *cache*, like Redis, which has very fast lookups.  You *could* also use a database, but that would be about 100 times slower than a good cache tool.  Regarding pruning the cache, when a user no longer requires the old JWT state, you may delete his entry.  This can be automated, perhaps, by assigning an expiry to the cache entry when you write it.